# how to use window partiton in ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, disk-usage

I don't have enough space in Ubuntu's partitions and want to use space from the Windows partitions for Ubuntu, as there's enough space in my Windows partitions.

`sudo parted -l && lsblk | grep -v "loop" && df -h | grep -v loop|tempfs` shows:

```
Model: ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  524MB   523MB   ntfs               msftdata
 2      524MB   629MB   105MB   fat32        EF    boot, esp
 3      629MB   646MB   16.8MB               Mi    hidden, msftres
 4      646MB   151GB   150GB   ntfs         Ba    msftdata
 5      151GB   152GB   490MB   ntfs               hidden, diag
 6      152GB   152GB   492MB   ntfs               hidden, diag
 7      152GB   362GB   210GB   ntfs               msftdata
 8      362GB   573GB   211GB   ntfs               msftdata
 9      573GB   784GB   211GB   ntfs               msftdata
10      784GB   895GB   111GB   ntfs               msftdata
11      895GB   1000GB  105GB   ext4


NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
|-sda1    8:1    0   499M  0 part 
|-sda2    8:2    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
|-sda3    8:3    0    16M  0 part 
|-sda4    8:4    0 140.1G  0 part /media/emad/5C0420F50420D3B4
|-sda5    8:5    0   467M  0 part 
|-sda6    8:6    0   469M  0 part 
|-sda7    8:7    0 195.7G  0 part 
|-sda8    8:8    0 196.3G  0 part /media/emad/01D3D823E95C1F60
|-sda9    8:9    0 196.3G  0 part 
|-sda10   8:10   0 103.5G  0 part 
`-sda11   8:11   0  98.2G  0 part /
sr0      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  ~
```

i have tried to mount the drive containing windows system partition but now i'm confused and still i don't have enough space.

for mounting the drive containing windows system partition i used disks program and i selected the drive and i selected gear icon below the partition and i selected "edit mount options" then i added following text at the end of the text box:

```
,remove_hiberfile
```

now i don't know what to do please help me.

Comment: Why do you have four additional Windows partitions, sda7 (210 GB), sda8 (211 GB), sda9 (211 GB),, and sda10 (111 GB), in addition to the 150 GB partition sda4 ? What's in those, and can their contents be moved off them so space can be added do your sda11 which contains Ubuntu? Also, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?

Comment: You should NOT mount the Windows C: drive in Ubuntu, and modify it in any way. You WILL create problems in Windows, guaranteed. Edit your question and show me a screenshot of gparted, and tell me briefly what's on each partition, and where you can afford to change partition sizes. The BEST scenario for sharing files is to create one or more NTFS partitions, as both OS's can read/write to them (but again, don't use the C: drive for this).

Comment: Also, ONLY make changes to the C: partition, or any NTFS partitions, using Windows `Disk Management` application. Use `gparted` for changing Linux ext2/3/4/swap partitions.

Comment: Lastly, you should NOT install ANY Windows driver that allows you to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions. You WILL corrupt Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, I'd suggest you take space from Windows, permanently, and give it to Ubuntu by repartitioning the hard drive. That's far easier to use once completed, and not that complex to do. However, here's what you asked for.

https://www.maketecheasier.com/write-windows-partition-linux/ explains you will be able to read from and write into the NTFS partitions from Ubuntu, if you use Restart to exit from Windows instead of Shut Down.  Please, however, avoid writing into C: because that's where Windows itself is, and you don't want to break Windows by changing some essential bit of code.

When you Shut Down, the default settings of Windows prevent the system from actually completely shutting down. Instead, the Fast Boot option of Windows copies from the contents of the Windows OS into the hard drive (or SSD if you have one of those), so Windows starts up much faster next time. It's a convenience for users and makes Windows look much better than Linux.

However, that means the drive partitions are locked and you can't write into them from the Nautilus File Manager or other Ubuntu apps if you boot into Ubuntu.

You can disable that feature from within Windows by right-clicking on the {START} button, choose Power Options, then Additional Power Options. Pick 'Choose what the power button does" then click on “Change settings that are currently unavailable.” Deselect “Turn on fast startup,” and then click the “Save changes” button at the bottom-right of the window so Windows won't lock those drives.  This is shown at the web link in the second paragraph of this post.

You should also open your BIOS/firmware settings of your PC's hardware to turn off Fast Boot or Fast Start if those appear as options in the BIOS/firmware. I don't know which model of PC you have so I can't tell you how to get into the BIOS, but when the PC is turned back on in a cold start (when fast startup is disabled), most models will tell you what key to press to get into Setup.

PS: Do *NOT* use Hibernation, either in Windows or Ubuntu, as that locks up drives just like Fast Start does.

Comment: You should change "*you will be able to read from and write into those Windows partitions from Ubuntu*" to "*you will be able to read from and write into those NTFS partitions from Ubuntu*". We don't want to encourage changes in the Windows C: drive from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly agree with 
K7AAY.After all that go into ubuntu, start gparted,en maked your changes.
You can also use a live cd (pendrive) of gparted.  Heve you find all what you need:

https://gparted.org/liveusb.php